# some data is not entered during insert process

Tags: php, mysql, file, glob

i tried to grab data from 2 different directory but have same format data, the directory name i put in database. when same type, it should be insert to another table with different head because from 2 different directory.
when i echo $query, it display all the data from 2 directory. but when insert just data from one directory entered.

here's

TABLE 2

```
INSERT INTO CMP.LOG_FILE(CMPTR_NBR,PRN_TTL,PRN_DESC,PRN_TYP,FIL_NM,PRN_DIM,BEG_TS,END_TS) VALUES ('1','CAMPUS10','CAMPUS10','Print','32429 ELLY','1400.175049 x 2749.550049 cm','2018-01-28 19:00:58','2018-01-28 19:00:58')
INSERT INTO CMP.LOG_FILE(CMPTR_NBR,PRN_TTL,PRN_DESC,PRN_TYP,FIL_NM,PRN_DIM,BEG_TS,END_TS) VALUES ('1','CAMPUS10','CAMPUS10','Print','32429 ELLY','1400.175049 x 2747.786133 cm','2018-01-28 19:41:41','2018-01-28 19:41:41')
INSERT INTO CMP.LOG_FILE(CMPTR_NBR,PRN_TTL,PRN_DESC,PRN_TYP,FIL_NM,PRN_DIM,BEG_TS,END_TS) VALUES ('1','CAMPUS10','CAMPUS10','Print','32429 ELLY','1400.175049 x 2749.550049 cm','2018-01-28 20:07:11','2018-01-28 20:07:11')
INSERT INTO CMP.LOG_FILE(CMPTR_NBR,PRN_TTL,PRN_DESC,PRN_TYP,FIL_NM,PRN_DIM,BEG_TS,END_TS) VALUES ('1','CAMPUS10','CAMPUS10','Print','32273 PRINTING_YOPIE','1500.011108 x 1000.125000 cm','2018-01-24 19:49:32','2018-01-24 19:49:32')
INSERT INTO CMP.LOG_FILE(CMPTR_NBR,PRN_TTL,PRN_DESC,PRN_TYP,FIL_NM,PRN_DIM,BEG_TS,END_TS) VALUES ('1','CAMPUS10','CAMPUS10','Print','46x46_bantal_fix.tif ','1080.205566 x 369.711121 cm','2018-01-30 15:55:11','2018-01-30 15:55:11')
INSERT INTO CMP.LOG_FILE(CMPTR_NBR,PRN_TTL,PRN_DESC,PRN_TYP,FIL_NM,PRN_DIM,BEG_TS,END_TS) VALUES ('3','CAMPUS12','CAMPUS12','Print','Sali - rzq_1Feb18 + reject 1x.tif ','1299.986084 x 920.044434 cm','2018-02-01 12:29:59','2018-02-01 12:29:59')
INSERT INTO CMP.LOG_FILE(CMPTR_NBR,PRN_TTL,PRN_DESC,PRN_TYP,FIL_NM,PRN_DIM,BEG_TS,END_TS) VALUES ('3','CAMPUS12','CAMPUS12','Print','kode 4 3x.tif ','470.252777 x 940.152771 cm','2018-01-31 20:03:20','2018-01-31 20:03:20')
INSERT INTO CMP.LOG_FILE(CMPTR_NBR,PRN_TTL,PRN_DESC,PRN_TYP,FIL_NM,PRN_DIM,BEG_TS,END_TS) VALUES ('3','CAMPUS12','CAMPUS12','Print','kode 9 3x.tif ','470.252777 x 940.152771 cm','2018-01-31 19:54:15','2018-01-31 19:54:15')
```

but when click insert just all data campus10 entered, not campus12.

TABLE 1

```
CMPTR_NBR    CMPTR_NAME    MACH_TYP      DIR_NAME
    1        CAMPUS10      MVJ1624     C://xampp/htdocs/Champion/machine-logs/LogCampusMesinMutoh/*.job 
    2        CAMPUS12      MVJ1624     C://xampp/htdocs/Champion/machine-logs/LogCampusMesinMutoh2/*.job
```

here's a piece function of code insert

```
else if ($row['MACH_TYP'] == 'MVJ1624') 
{

    foreach (glob($row['DIR_NAME'])as $job) { //local
        // echo $job."<br>";
    if (file_exists($job)) { 
        $path           = file_get_contents($job);
        $File           = '/File=(.*)/';
        $PrintSetup     = '/PrintSetup=(.*)/';
        $SourceSizeX    = '/SourceSizeX=(.*)/';
        $SourceSizeY    = '/SourceSizeY=(.*)/';
        $Filelg         = '/File=(.*)/';

        preg_match($File,         $path, $Filematch);
        preg_match($PrintSetup,   $path, $PrintSetupmatch);
        preg_match($SourceSizeX,  $path, $SourceSizeXmatch);
        preg_match($SourceSizeY,  $path, $SourceSizeYmatch);
        preg_match($Filelg,       $path, $Filelgmatch);

        $kol     = $Filelgmatch[1];

        $str     = str_replace('File=', '', $kol);

        $folders = explode('\\', $str);
        $realtime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", filemtime($job));
        $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($realtime.'+ 6 hour'));
         // echo $time."<br>";

        $dimensi = $SourceSizeXmatch[1]." x ".$SourceSizeYmatch[1]." cm";

        $testing = $folders[6];
        $query = "INSERT INTO CMP.LOG_FILE(CMPTR_NBR,PRN_TTL,PRN_DESC,PRN_TYP,FIL_NM,PRN_DIM,BEG_TS,END_TS) VALUES ('".$row['CMPTR_NBR']."','".$row['CMPTR_NAME']."','".$row['CMPTR_NAME']."','Print','".$testing."','".$dimensi."','".$time."','".$time."')";
          echo $query."<br>";
        // $result = mysql_query($query);
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you add the result of `show create table CMP.LOG_FILE;` please?

Comment: 1
CAMPUS10
CAMPUS10
Print
32429 ELLY
1400.175049
x 2749.550049
cm
2018-01-28 19:00:58
2018-01-28 19:00:58

Comment: This is not the result of [`show create table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html).

Comment: CREATE TABLE `log_file` (
 `CMPTR_NBR` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `PRN_TTL` char(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `PRN_DESC` char(50) NOT NULL,
 `PRN_TYP` char(100) NOT NULL,
 `FIL_NM` char(100) NOT NULL,
 `PRN_DIM` char(50) NOT NULL,
 `BEG_TS` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `END_TS` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `DUR_PRN` char(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see what's wrong. Try to print error from mysql could help.

Comment: yeah, the problem in directory. if i change 1 type to worng type. it entered. so just can use 1 directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164446/discussion-between-beny-bond-banjarnahor-and-syscall).